# Direction of a 2D complex vector

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vectors

I am writing a trivial algebra library in order to learn some concepts.
I have a vector implementation that works fine for operations with Real values. When it comes to complex numbers the thing gets a bit more… coumbersome.

Currently, I am trying to calculate the direction (in radiants) of a complex vector in 2D.
For normal vectors in 2D (real values) I simply use a function given by the library, atan2, which takes 2 arguments and computes atan while considering the signs to find the correct quadrant. Something like:
`atan2(y,x)`
But I cannot do this with complex numbers.

NB: With complex vector I mean that each component is a complex number

Is there a formula or another way to compute the direction of my complex vector in 2D?

Comment: Do you mean a single imaginary value or two imaginary values? Complex numbers are a two dimensional space over the reals, but a one dimensional space over the complex numbers.

Comment: Each component is a complex number, Ill make that clear in the post now

Comment: With two complex vectors there is no meaningful way to get a direction because the complex numbers are not an ordered field.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification